# How can I tell if a driveItem is a folder?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I am trying to show an icon for driveItems, in most cases this works by just getting the extension part of the driveItem name.

However, I have files with no extensions, and folders (with no extensions) showing up as the same icon.

Is there a good way using the dotnet Graph SDK to determine if a driveItem is a folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`driveItem` resource has properties `folder` and `file`.

`folder` property is set if the item is a folder.

`file` property is set if the item is a file.

To determine if the items is either a folder or a file for dotnet Graph SDK check properties [folder](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/blob/127f3f531928cf2d4b29671a27419f3e2a67fd97/src/Microsoft.Graph/Generated/model/DriveItem.cs#L85) and [file](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/blob/127f3f531928cf2d4b29671a27419f3e2a67fd97/src/Microsoft.Graph/Generated/model/DriveItem.cs#L71) if their are `null` or have value.

Resources:

[driveItem properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/driveitem?view=graph-rest-1.0#properties)